# Make your own gas line for fire pit?

Tags: gas

I have a 1/2 gas line that I ran a couple years ago outside to my back patio for a fire pit.  My problem is the burner that I bought does not put out a large enough flame.  I want to make my own "burner" by taking a pipe and just drilling some holes into it.

If one were to take a straight pipe off the natural gas line in the house and ignite it at the end, what prevents the gas from igniting INSIDE the pipe and blowing up the whole house?  From what I've read, gas needs air to ignite, so that would prevent that from ever happening??  Or, is there some type of regulator needed (like on a propane tank) to keep it from backing up the line and igniting?

Comment: Sounds like a bad idea to me.

Comment: For natural gas to light, it needs about a 10 to 1 air to gas ratio.  The pressure in the pipe will prevent air from entering the pipe and blowing up the house.  But nothing prevents you from putting out too much gas at the pit, making the mixture too high to ignite until it gets about 10 feet away from the pit and then everything explodes.

Comment: Thank you Tester101, I appreciate the reply.  That's what I read online about the pressure preventing air from entering the pipe, but wanted to be sure.  I would have a shutoff valve at the other end that would enable me to regulate the flow of gas coming out.  Please correct me if I'm wrong.